# Accessing Vector elements gives me an error Rust

Tags: rust

I trying to write a program that will find the median of any given list.

Eventually, In the FINAL FINAL stretch, an error was shot into my face.

I tried to access elements of a `Vec`tor through a variable.

Take a look at the `calc_med()` function.

```rust
use std::io;
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

lazy_static! {
    static ref num_list: Mutex<Vec<f64>> = Mutex::new(Vec::new());
}

fn main() {
    loop {
        println!("Enter: ");

        let mut inp: String = String::new();

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut inp).expect("Failure");

        let upd_inp: f64 = match inp.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => {
                if inp.trim() == String::from("q") {
                    break;
                } else if inp.trim() == String::from("d") {
                    break {
                        println!("Done!");
                        calc_med();
                    };
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        };

        num_list.lock().unwrap().push(upd_inp);
        num_list
            .lock()
            .unwrap()
            .sort_by(|a, b| a.partial_cmp(b).unwrap());

        println!("{:?}", num_list.lock().unwrap());
    }
}

fn calc_med() {
    // FOR THE ATTENTION OF STACKOVERFLOW
    let n: f64 = ((num_list.lock().unwrap().len()) as f64 + 1.0) / 2.0;

    if n.fract() == 0.0 {
        let n2: usize = n as usize;
    } else {
        let n3: u64 = n.round() as u64;
        let n4: usize = n3 as usize;

        let median: f64 = (num_list[n4] + num_list[n4 - 1]) / 2;
        println!("{}", median);
    }
}
```

The error is as following:

```
   Compiling FindTheMedian v0.1.0 (/home/isaak/Documents/Code/Rusty/FindTheMedian)
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `num_list`
  --> src/main.rs:50:28
   |
50 |         let median: f64 = (num_list[n4] + num_list[n4 - 1]) / 2;
   |                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `num_list`
  --> src/main.rs:50:43
   |
50 |         let median: f64 = (num_list[n4] + num_list[n4 - 1]) / 2;
   |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Please copy the error text directly into your question. DO NOT post it as an image.

Comment: Rust will make this a lot easier for you if you just keep the vector as a local variable in main and pass it directly into `calc_med`.

Comment: Regardless, all you need to do is use `lock().unwrap()` (like you do at the top of the fn) to get access to the `Vec` within the `Mutex`.

Comment: @PitaJ Where do I use lock().unwrap()? I tried it a few times in different areas...

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean when I say it's easier to just pass the vector around: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=577fa546a22b5b24f04e656fc961b104

Comment: @PitaJ Thank you so much, I'm still just a beginner to RustLang and that was a real help.

Comment: Nitpick: prefer `once_cell` to `lazy_static`. Also, in new Rust versions, you don't need `lazy_static` for `Mutex` as `Mutex::new()` is `const fn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is the `num_list` is not an vector, it's a mutex with an vector inside of it. To access the value inside of a mutex, you must `lock` it, and then `unwrap` the result. You do this correctly in `main`.

To avoid continually unlocking and locking, it is generally best practice to lock the mutex once, at the start of the function. Rust will automatically drop the lock when the reference goes out of scope. See the updated example:

```rust
fn calc_med() { // FOR THE ATTENTION OF STACKOVERFLOW
    let nums = num_list.lock().unwrap();
    let n: f64 = (nums.len() as f64 + 1.0) / 2.0;

    if n.fract() == 0.0 {
        let n2: usize = n as usize;
    } else {
        let n3: u64 = n.round() as u64;
        let n4: usize = n3 as usize;
        
        let median: f64 = (nums[n4] + nums[n4 - 1]) / 2;
        println!("{}", median);
    }
}
```

Comment: nit: You don't 'have to' unwrap the `Result` of `lock` but it's often the most concise option and usually also sensible.

Comment: fair @cafce25, felt it was appropriate in this context due to the liberal use of `unwrap` in the OP

Answer (score 2):

The current code is trying to index a variable of type `Mutex<Vec<f64>>`, which is not valid. The way you access the underlying data in a mutex is by calling `.lock()` on it, which will in turn return a structure that resembles `Result<Vec<f64>, Error>`.

So, fixing only the line would look like this:

```rs
let num_list_vec = num_list.lock().unwrap();
let median: f64 = (num_list_vec[n4] + num_list_vec[n4 - 1]) / 2;
```

However, since you already locked at the start of the function this will not work, since the mutex is already locked. The best way then is to do the locking + unwraping at the start of the function and use the underlying value in all places:

```rs
fn calc_med() {
    let num_list_vec = num_list.lock().unwrap();
    let n: f64 = ((num_list_vec.len()) as f64 + 1.0) / 2.0;

    if n.fract() == 0.0 {
        let n2: usize = n as usize;
    } else {
        let n3: u64 = n.round() as u64;
        let n4: usize = n3 as usize;

        let median: f64 = (num_list_vec[n4] + num_list_vec[n4 - 1]) / 2;
        println!("{}", median);
    }
}
```

Edit: Checking your main, I see you are also `lock().unwrap()`ing in sequence a lot, which is not the way `Mutex` should be used. `Mutex` is mainly used whenever you have a need for multi-threaded programming, so that different threads cannot access the same variable twice. It also incurs a performance hit, so you shouldn't really use it in single-threaded scenarios most of the time.

Unless there's a bigger picture we're missing, you should just define your `Vec` in `main` and pass it to `calc_med` as an argument. If the reason you did what you did was to get it as a global, there are other ways to do that in Rust without performance hits, but due to safe design of Rust these ways are not encouraged and should only be used if you know 100% what you want.